# "Bad request" accessing API Gateway with signed request from React Native

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to call an API Gateway endpoint from a React Native application using [aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-react-native) and a regular `fetch` call.
The API Gateway endpoint requires IAM authorization. For that purpose I've set up an AWS Cognito Federated Identity Pool and configured the Unauthenticated IAM Role to have execution permission over the API.

The code below runs on my React Native app and is supposed to get a new token from Cognito and use it to sign a request to the API Gateway endpoint. Unfortunately every time I run it I receive an html error response as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<TITLE>ERROR: The request could not be satisfied</TITLE>
</HEAD><BODY>
<H1>ERROR</H1>
<H2>The request could not be satisfied.</H2>
<HR noshade size="1px">
Bad request.
<BR clear="all">
<HR noshade size="1px">
<PRE>
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
Request ID: fiYpmNCsqwm7D9yUjNOmBCLisxtKNBiV2EO6X-eeKpbpmwk6rkkMJQ==
</PRE>
<ADDRESS>
</ADDRESS>
</BODY></HTML>
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong...

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk/dist/aws-sdk-react-native';

let region = 'us-west-2';
AWS.config.region = region;
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
});

let host = 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com';
let route = '/beta/api/foo';
let url = `${host}${route}`;

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
    console.log('AWS.config.credentials', AWS.config.credentials);

    var httpRequest = new AWS.HttpRequest(url);
    httpRequest.method = 'GET';
    httpRequest.path = route;
    httpRequest.region = region;
    httpRequest.headers['Host'] = host;
    httpRequest.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json";

    var service = "execute-api";
    var v4signer = new AWS.Signers.V4(httpRequest, service);
    v4signer.addAuthorization(AWS.config.credentials, new Date());

    fetch(url, httpRequest)
        .then( resp => {
           console.log('API gateway response', resp)
           // Should receive JSON, but currently getting text with HTML error message
           // return resp.json();
           return resp.text();
        })
        .then(txt => {
           console.log("API Gateway result", txt)
        })
        .catch( err => {
           console.log('Failed call to API Gateway', err)
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As written, your code will set the Host header to 'https://xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'

The host header should only contain the DNS name of the host, so it should just be 'xxxxxxx.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com'